# Return an opaque object to the caller without violating type-safety

Tags: c#, type-safety

I have a method which should return a snapshot of the current state, and another method which restores that state.

```
public class MachineModel
{
    public Snapshot CurrentSnapshot { get; }
    public void RestoreSnapshot (Snapshot saved) { /* etc */ };
}
```

The state `Snapshot` class should be completely opaque to the caller--no visible methods or properties--but its properties have to be visible within the `MachineModel` class. I could obviously do this by downcasting, i.e. have `CurrentSnapshot` return an `object`, and have `RestoreSnapshot` accept an `object` argument which it casts back to a `Snapshot`.

But forced casting like that makes me feel dirty. What's the best alternate design that allows me to be both type-safe and opaque?

**Update with solution**:

I wound up doing a combination of the accepted answer and the suggestion about interfaces. The `Snapshot` class was made a public abstract class, with a private implementation inside `MachineModel`:

```
public class MachineModel
{
    public abstract class Snapshot
    {
        protected internal Snapshot() {}
        abstract internal void Restore(MachineModel model);
    }

    private class SnapshotImpl : Snapshot
    {
        /* etc */
    }

    public void Restore(Snapshot state)
    {
        state.Restore(this);
    }
}
```

Because the constructor and methods of `Snapshot` are `internal`, callers from outside the assembly see it as a completely opaque and cannot inherit from it. Callers within the assembly could call `Snapshot.Restore` rather than `MachineModel.Restore`, but that's not a big problem. Furthermore, in practice you could never implement `Snapshot.Restore` without access to `MachineModel`'s private members, which should dissuade people from trying to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse the dependency and make Snapshot a child (nested class) of MachineModel. Then Snapshot only has a public (or internal) `Restore()` method which takes as a parameter an instance of MachineModel. Because Snapshot is defined as a child of MachineModel, it can see MachineModel's private fields.

To restore the state, you have two options in the example below. You can call Snapshot.RestoreState(MachineModel) or MachineModel.Restore(Snapshot)*.

```
public class MachineModel
{
    public class Snapshot
    {
        int _mmPrivateField;

        public Snapshot(MachineModel mm) 
        { 
            // get mm's state
            _mmPrivateField = mm._privateField;
        }

        public void RestoreState(MachineModel mm) 
        { 
            // restore mm's state
            mm._privateField = _mmPrivateField;
        }
    }

    int _privateField;

    public Snapshot CurrentSnapshot
    {
        get { return new Snapshot(this); }
    }

    public void RestoreState(Snapshot ss)
    {
        ss.Restore(this);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
    MachineModel mm1 = new MachineModel();
    MachineModel.Snapshot ss = mm1.CurrentSnapshot;
    MachineModel mm2 = new MachineModel();
    mm2.RestoreState(ss);
```

* It would be neater to have Snapshot.RestoreState() as `internal` and put all callers outside the assembly, so the only way to do a restore is via MachineModel.RestoreState(). But you mentioned on Jon's answer that there will be callers inside the same assembly, so there isn't much point.

Answer (score 3):

Can `MachineModel` and `Snapshot` be in the same assembly, and callers in a different assembly? If so, `Snapshot` could be a public class but with entirely internal members.

Comment: `MachineModel` will have callers both from within the same assembly and from outside assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

> I could obviously do this by
>   downcasting, i.e. have CurrentSnapshot
>   return an object, and have
>   RestoreSnapshot accept an object
>   argument which it casts back to a
>   Snapshot.

The problem is that somebody could then pass an instance of an object which is not `Snapshot`.

If you introduce an **interface** `ISnapshot` which exposes no methods, and only one implementation exists, you can almost ensure type-safety at the price of a downcast.

I say almost, because you can not completely prevent somebody from creating another implementation of `ISnapshot` and pass it, which would break. But I feel like that should provide the desired level of information hiding.

Comment: Funny, I just wrote the code below and was curious how others would write it so I googled. I did exactly what you said..

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but i was looking for something very similar and I ended up here and between the information reported here and some other I came up with this solution, maybe is a little overkill, but this way the state object is fully opaque, even at the assembly level

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething l_Class = new DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine("Seed: {0}", l_Class.Seed);

        Console.WriteLine("Saving State");

        DoSomething.SomeState l_State = l_Class.Save_State();

        l_Class.Regen_Seed();

        Console.WriteLine("Regenerated Seed: {0}", l_Class.Seed);

        Console.WriteLine("Restoring State");

        l_Class.Restore_State(l_State);

        Console.WriteLine("Restored Seed: {0}", l_Class.Seed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class DoSomething
{
    static Func<DoSomething, SomeState> g_SomeState_Ctor;

    static DoSomething()
    {
        Type type = typeof(SomeState);
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);
    }

    Random c_Rand = new Random();

    public DoSomething()
    {
        Seed = c_Rand.Next();
    }

    public SomeState Save_State()
    {
        return g_SomeState_Ctor(this);
    }

    public void Restore_State(SomeState f_State)
    {
        ((ISomeState)f_State).Restore_State(this);
    }

    public void Regen_Seed()
    {
        Seed = c_Rand.Next();
    }

    public int Seed { get; private set; }

    public class SomeState : ISomeState
    {
        static SomeState()
        {
            g_SomeState_Ctor = (DoSomething f_Source) => { return new SomeState(f_Source); };
        }

        private SomeState(DoSomething f_Source) { Seed = f_Source.Seed; }

        void ISomeState.Restore_State(DoSomething f_Source)
        {
            f_Source.Seed = Seed;
        }

        int Seed { get; set; }
    }

    private interface ISomeState
    {
        void Restore_State(DoSomething f_Source);
    }
}
```